# Some issue concerning fprint and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, operating-system, printf

I am taking an OS course and I have some questions about the following codes

```
#include <stdio.h>
int * addition(int a, int b){
    int c = a + b;
    int *d = &c;
    return d;
}
int main(void){
    int result = *(addition(1,2));
    int *result_ptr = addition(1,2);
    /*never interchange */
    printf("result = %d\n", *result_ptr);
    printf("result = %d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
//this code outputs 3
                    3
```

Here is what happens when i swap the printfs, in fact the second one just prints out a random address

```
#include <stdio.h>
int * addition(int a, int b){
    int c = a + b;
    int *d = &c;
    return d;
}
int main(void){
    int result = *(addition(1,2));
    int *result_ptr = addition(1,2);
    /*never interchange */
    printf("result = %d\n", result);
    printf("result = %d\n", *result_ptr);
    return 0;
}
//this code outputs 3
                    and a random address
```

However, if i make them into one printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int * addition(int a, int b){
    int c = a + b;
    int *d = &c;
    return d;
}
int main(void){
    int result = *(addition(1,2));
    int *result_ptr = addition(1,2);
    /*never interchange */
    printf("result = %d %d \n", result, *result_ptr);
    return 0;
}
//this code outputs 3 3
```

I wonder if the printf clear the memory so the pointer becomes dangerous?

Comment: in the 'addition()' function, the returned pointer points to a variable on the stack.  That stack variable 'goes out of scope' when the function exits (therefore is no longer valid and exhibits undefined behaviour which can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: this statement: `int result = *(addition(1,2));` works.  this statment: `int *result_ptr = addition(1,2);` now has a pointer to 'somewhere' on the stack.  That somewhere is no longer valid (I.E. undefined behaviour to deref' that pointer.

Comment: the 'printf()' clobbers the stack where the variable was at, as it implements its' own stack values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `addition` function.  You're returning the address of a local variable.  Because locals live on the stack, the memory for that variable goes out of scope when the function returns.  This caused undefined behavior such as what you experienced.

For this to work properly, you need to allocate memory on the heap using `malloc`:

```
int *addition(int a, int b){
    int *d = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *d = a + b;
    return d;
}
```

When this function returns, you need to be sure to `free` the pointer that was returned after you're done with it.  Otherwise, you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact , my professor write the addition function and ask us to explain the outcomes of the first 2  pieces of codes

Comment: Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: But I don't understand why the first piece of code prints out two 3s

Comment: @ergutebao Undefined behavior(UB) means anything can be the result. It might work the first time, but fail, when you make some minor changes. Read more on UB to understand more.